# Arduino SIM900 No SMS received

Tags: gsm

I tried the tutorial in this link

https://lastminuteengineers.com/sim900-gsm-shield-arduino-tutorial/

to send an SMS message using a SIM900 GSM shield

I completed the section to send AT commands successfully but I can't get
the Arduino Uno to send an SMS. Below is the output I get after doing AT command tests

```
Initializing...
AT

OK
AT+CPIN?

+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CSQ

+CSQ: 6,0

OK
AT+CCID

8944500105191448516F

OK
AT+CREG?

+CREG: 0,5

OK
AT+COPS?

+COPS: 0,0,"T-Mobile "

OK
AT+COPS=?

+COPS: (2,"T-Mobile ","T-Mobile ","310260"),,(0,1,4),(0,1,2)

OK
```

and below are the responses from the SMS code

```
Initializing...
AT

OK
AT+CMGF=1

OK
AT+CMGS="+1mycellphonenumber" 

> Last Minute Engineers | lastminuteengineers.com
```

so no response from the AT+CMGS command and NO SMS received. 
Plug is 5V 2A.

Any idea what might be causing the issue?

Below is the code I used for the Setup() function

```
void setup()
{
  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and Arduino IDE (Serial Monitor)
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Begin serial communication with Arduino and SIM900
  mySerial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT"); //Handshaking with SIM900
  updateSerial();

  mySerial.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Configuring TEXT mode
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+ZZxxxxxxxxxx\"");//change ZZ with country code and xxxxxxxxxxx with phone number to sms
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.print("Last Minute Engineers | lastminuteengineers.com"); //text content
  updateSerial();
  mySerial.write(26);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Changed my SIM card to Ting from Hologram and it worked just fine!

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer as the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Normally in Setup() you have in the end this sequence

```
Serial.println("Connecting to the network...");

while( (sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 500) ||
    sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,5", 500)) == 0 );

     sprintf(aux_str, "ATD%s;", phone_number);
     sendATcommand(aux_str, "OK", 10000);

     delay(seconds * 1000);

    Serial.println("ATH"); // disconnects the existing call
```

So after the registering you send

```
 Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"1234567890\""); //CHANGE TO DESTINATION NUMBER
```

Did you use the \" for the embracing the number. Without your real command its hard to guess. Better use a [test program Soft Serial GPRS Code](https://researchdesignlab.com/modules/gsm-modem-arduino-compatible.html), serial monitor is error prone.
**EDIT** The OP posted code parts. The code after:

```
  Serial.println("Initializing..."); 
  delay(1000);
```

should be in the loop()- Look at the linked examples how should communication take place if the code is run once so no recurring tasks like reading chars or similar.

Comment: I posted the Setup() function code I used above, the line below is to send the SMS. mySerial.println("AT+CMGS=\"+1mycellphonenumber\"");